# What do you call a person who lies or criticizes others and refuses to acknowledge their own mistakes?

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you call a person who lies or criticizes others and refuses to acknowledge their own mistakes? I know a person who is quick to retaliate with "what about your actions" questions whenever someone criticizes him.

Comment: Funny how nobody ever shows up here asking for our help in saying something ***nice*** about somebody else. Instead it's always about saying horrible things about something we disapprove of, even though this has never required fancy words to sting the worst.

Answer (score 1):

I guess narcissistic person
is a mental condition in which people have an inflated sense of their own importance, a deep need for excessive attention and admiration, troubled relationships, and a lack of empathy for others.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

> What do you call a person who lies or criticizes others and refuses to acknowledge their own mistakes?

This part falls well within narcissistic behaviour as earlier noted by @Chahira Bengharbi.

Here is what wikipedia says about characteristics of it:

> Narcissism refers to a "pervasive pattern of grandiosity", which is characterized by feelings of entitlement and superiority, arrogant or haughty behaviors, and a generalized lack of empathy and concern for others. ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissism#Characteristics))

However I think next part is about how a person handles an argument:

> I know a person who is quick to retaliate with "what about your actions" questions whenever someone criticizes him.

This is whataboutism and ad hominem. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fallacies

Comment: The question was after a single word that encapsulates both parts.

Comment: I would still use word narcissistic, since a narcissistic person would easily sway into logical fallacies to support his/her argument. I just wanted to point that the question is loaded with multiple questions inside.